# Fork command to create tree of processes, failing to show ppids

Tags: c, tree, fork

I am trying to create a tree of processes to look like:
F \
  |\1 \
  |   |\3
  |    \4
   \2 
F and 1 shall wait for their children to be terminated. Somehow, all parents pids are indicated as 1. Secondly, process I have recognized as "Father of them all" - F does not seem to be the real father.
here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (){
    int status;

    pid_t child_1;

    child_1 = fork();

    if(child_1 == 0){ //This is the child 1 process.
        printf("child 1:%d, %d\n", getpid());

        int returnStatus;
        waitpid(child_1, &returnStatus, 0);

        pid_t child_3 = fork();

        if(child_3 == 0){ //This is the child 3 process.
            printf("child 3:%d, %d\n", getpid());
            printf("parent child 3:%d\n", getppid());

        }

        else if(child_3 > 0){ // This is the father of child 3.

            pid_t child_4 = fork();

            if(child_4 == 0){ //This is the child 4 process.
                printf("child 4:%d, %d\n", getpid());
                printf("parent child 4:%d\n", getppid());

            }

        }
    }

    else { // This is the father of all processes.

        int returnStatus;
        waitpid(child_1, &returnStatus, 0);

        printf("FATHER OF THEM ALL:%d\n", getpid());

        pid_t child_2 = fork();

        if(child_2 == 0){ // This is the child 2 process.
            printf("child 2:%d, %d\n", getpid());

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the calls to `printf()` to print the results of a call to `getpid()` have two format specifiers, but only one data parameter.  Suggest removing the second format specifier.

Comment: regarding: `else { // This is the father of all processes.`  There are three(3) kinds of returned values from a call to `fork()`  1) <0 means an error occurred  2) ==0 means in the child process 3) >0 means in the parent process.  The posted code fails to check for the <0 condition

Comment: regarding: `waitpid(child_1, &returnStatus, 0);` that statement is located within the child process.  A process cannot wait on itself.  And the variable `child_1` contains 0, so, in this case, it will returns a `-1` because there is no child of child_1 to wait upon

Comment: regarding: ` pid_t child_2 = fork();

        if(child_2 == 0){ // This is the child 2 process.
            printf("child 2:%d, %d\n", getpid());`  The parent needs to NOT exit until all its' child processes have exited.  The posted code does not do that.  In older systems, this would result in the production of `zombies`.  In modern systems the child process are attached (in linux) to the `init` process.  Neither condition is good, (although attaching to `init` is much better than becoming a zombie

Answer (score 0):

suggest a layout similar to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main ( void )
{
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    switch( pid1 )
    {
        case -1:
            perror( "fork for child1 failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break; 

        case 0:
            printf( "child1 pid: %d\n", getpid() );
            pid_t pid2 = fork();
            switch( pid2 )
            {
                case -1:
                    perror( "fork for child2 failed" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    break;

                case 0:
                    printf( "child2 pid: %d\n", getpid() ); 
                    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                    break;

                default: // in child 1
                { // braces so can have data declaration
                    int status2; 
                    waitpid( pid2, &status2, 0 );
                    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;

         default: // in original parent
         {
             int status1;
             waitpid( pid1, &status1, 0 );
         }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

which properly handles child1 and child2.  In the `default` case for child1, could insert code for a 3rd and 4th child process of child 1

Comment: Thank you all for your great help.